# PHP Regex: match text urls until space or end of string

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match, preg-match-all

This is the text sample:

```
$text = "asd dasjfd fdsfsd http://11111.com/asdasd/?s=423%423%2F gfsdf http://22222.com/asdasd/?s=423%423%2F
asdfggasd http://3333333.com/asdasd/?s=423%423%2F";
```

This is my regex pattern:

```
preg_match_all( "#http:\/\/(.*?)[\s|\n]#is", $text, $m );
```

That match the first two urls, but how do I match the last one? I tried adding [\s|\n|$] but that will also only match the first two urls.

Comment: Did not work. Whatever that means. I'm pretty sure the pattern always works.

Comment: @hakre it doesn't match the 3rd url, only the first two.

Comment: `|` are used in `()` not in `[]` to say *or*. Have you tried: `(\s|\n|$)` or `(?:\s|\n|$)`? (`?:` makes the group non matching) - also, you could just add a space to `$text` ;)

Comment: @hakre (\s|\n|$) worked thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Don't try to match `\n` (there's no line break after all!) and instead use `$` (which will match to the end of the string).</s>

Edit:
I'd love to hear why my initial idea doesn't work, so in case you know it, let me know. I'd guess because `[]` tries to match one character, while end of line isn't one? :)

This one will work:

```
preg_match_all('#http://(\S+)#is', $text, $m);
```

Note that you don't have to escape the / due to them not being the delimiting character, but you'd have to escape the `\` as you're using double quotes (so the string is parsed). Instead I used single quotes for this.

Comment: "#http:\/\/(.*?)[\s|\n|$]#is" will not match the 3rd url for me.

Comment: Interesting, trying it now as well. It indeed doesn't match (also; as mentioned above; the | is obsolete (and interpreted as another possible value within `[]`).

Comment: Within the square brackets, `$` matches a literal `$`, just like `|` matches a literal `|`.  You would need to look for `(\s|$)`, as @dsrekab suggested (`\n` is redundant, as that's one of the characters matched by `\s`).  But I think the way you're doing it now is better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with PHP, so I don't have the exact syntax, but maybe this will give you something to try.  the [] means a character class so |$ will literally look for a $.  I think what you'll need is another look ahead so something like this:

```
#http:\/\/(.*)(?=(\s|$))
```

I apologize if this is way off, but maybe it will give you another angle to try.

Answer (score 0):

See [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/379580)

It has some very long regular expressions that will match all urls.